# Spring rollback transaction part

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I have spring & hibernate transaction configured (aop on each service call and roll back for Throwable). I need to support folowing requierements for cretePartA():

- should not fail main transaction,  cteateSmth() in my example
- shoud rollback it's own transaction if is failed

  service1.cteateSmth();

  ```
  /*started in new transaction*/
  public void cteateSmth()
  {
     //...some other inserts

     // should not fail main transaction, 
     // but shoud rollback it's own if is failed
     anotherService.cretePartA(); 

    //should save state in db in any case
    recordSmthCreation(); 
  }

  public void cretePartA(){
     updateSubpartA();
     updateSubPartA1();    
     if(!sucees) throw new ValidationException();

  }
  ```

In example above even wiht try catch wrapping for cretePartA(), entire cteateSmth() transaction will be rolled back.

I tried to this with REQUIRES_NEW , but it seems i can't rollback cretePartA() actions in such case.

```
TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionAttribute(TransactionDefinition.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW);
new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager, transactionDefinition).execute(new TransactionCallback()
{
    @Override
    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status)
    {
        try{
           cretePartA()
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

I tried to not create new transaction for cretePartA(), just excelude this service call from spring aop. But in this case result will be commmited for cretePartA().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with annotaion `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`
for cretePartA() method and try/catch block

Comment: Also good article http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2017/02/spring-transactions-managements.html